# How to Access an Specific String Value in Buffer Reader Android

Tags: android, bufferedreader

I have below code in my Android which is returning some results from my Php page based on post value of `user_name` and `password`

```
try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

On postExecute it is showing results like below

[image]

I need to access specific value like only `user_id` and `user_mobile`
how can I access this? Have no Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fetch values like this.

```
try {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
    String userId = jObj.getString("user_id");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + e);
}
```

Comment: How can I use it directly in onPostExecute method.It is throwing an Unhandled exception error

Comment: for that, you can use a try-catch block. check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks its working. Is it possible to use a for each loop for multiple result set

Comment: if you have something like `String[] result` or `List<String> result`, yes you can use it.